# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.3

Tags: android, gradle, repository

I am continuously facing problem: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.3

[image]

Although I have updated packages by going to the SDK Manager 

[image]

but still facing the same problem. Even when I am creating a new project the same problem persist. Kindly guide.

Comment: can you post your gradle file code

Answer (score 2):

The was no such version of Support libraries.

[Here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html) You can find the list.

I suggest using the newest: `25.0.0`.

Build tools version and support libraries version are completely different thing.

`buildToolsVersion` is a field in `build.gradle` configuration file in `android` closure.

Support libraries are declared in `dependencies` `closure`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have used 23.0.3 version. But you have installed the only the API 25 version.

First you should installed 23 version if you want to keep this configurations. Unless change this to 25 version as follows.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'

compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "it.com.test"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it with `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'`

Also update

`compileSdkVersion 25
 buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"`

Sync the gradle file and it will gonna work